# Two dice are rolled. Find the probability that at least one die is 6 if it is known that at least one die had an odd number.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So I have a question:

> Two dice are rolled. Find the probability that at least one die is 6 if it is known that at least one die had an odd number.

Is this the right way to calculate conditional probability?

If I understood correctly, then I need to find this

\begin{align}
P(A \mid B) &= \frac{AB}{B}
\end{align}

There is an event **A -> at least one die is 6**. First, I will find probability, that both dice don't have 6.

\begin{align}
P(\neg A) &= \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{25}{36} \\\\
\end{align}
So \begin{align}
P(A) &= 1 - \frac{25}{36} = \frac{11}{36} \\\\
\end{align}
Next, we have event **B -> came odd number**

\begin{align}
P(B) &= \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2} \\\\
\end{align}

In the end we have:
\begin{align}
P(A|B) &= \frac{\frac{11}{36} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{11}{36} = 0.305 \\\\
\end{align}

Does this look fine?

Comment: What you are looking for is $\frac{P(A\capB)} {P(B)} $ not $\frac{Ab} {B} $

Answer (score 3):

That's not correct. Also the question is not stated clearly. It says *at least* one of the dice is $6$. But if at least one of the dice is odd then either exactly one die is $6$ or none of them is $6$.

Event $A$ - one of the dice is $6$
Event $B$ - at least one of the dice is odd

Probability that *at least* one of the dice is odd

$ \displaystyle P(B) = 1 - \frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 = \frac 34 ~$, we take complement of the probability that none of the dice is odd.

$ \displaystyle P(A \cap B) = 2 \cdot \frac 12 \cdot \frac 16~$, as one of them is $6$ and the other is odd.

Now, $ \displaystyle P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$